# Do I get anything for my friends slipping on poop?

Tags: happy-street

If Poopy the Bird poops on the ground and I don't pick it up, my friends will slip on it and fall.

Does that do anything? I know if I poop on their heads I get money, but what about if I make them slip on it?

Answer (score 1):

If somebody slips on the poop, the people will leave and won't buy anything from the shops.